# Download from asp.net web app over ssl failing running on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl

I have an asp.net web app deployed on IIS7. I call the webapp AOps and When I try accessing the web app over https it just crashes saying "Security sertificate required to access this resource is invalid" (first image).

When I try over http the download works fine.

When I access the default IIS app over both http and https it works fine - except that it complains that the address is mismatched.

I have added a .pfx certificate in the certificate store with the same host name as my host, so the certificate should be fine. Any idea where to start reviewing my configuration?

I am used to apache and tomcat but IIS is a different animal. I looked in the IIS log but it's pretty much a black box. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: https]

[image: http]

[image: https default]
[image: http default]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The certificate error is generated by your browser not the server.  There are 3 things the browser cares about.

1. The name on the certificate needs to match the url you are using.  So in your case, the browser wants a certificate issued to "localhost"
2. The certificate has to be issued by a trusted certificate authority (not self-signed)
3. The certificate cannot be expired

To solve 1, use a host entry in /etc/hosts.  To solve 2, you need to add the certificate to trusted CA store on your local machine.  And 3 is pretty obvious.

Comment: Thanks alot. It was actually issue number one. I alternated between IP and localhost while the certificate in fact was issued to the hostname.